# Multiple instances of Fancybox not working

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I am new to HTML & CSS. I have created a page using Fancybox (2 instances on same page) and it works well on my local machine as well on my hosting server. However as soon as I migrate to my client's server the thumbnails disappear. Here are both links -

http://intelliassist.in/susheeljangiraapproved/photos.html (working fine) http://susheeljangira.com/photos.html (missing thumbnail).

Can anyone please recommend what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't upload all images on client server, about 39 images missing on http requests. The script is working fine only can't find the images.